# stock market news API

Tags: api, feed

does anyone know if there is a stock market news API out there? Hopefully one that covers the major publishers like Reuters, Bloomberg, NYT, and WSJ?

Comment: Newsriver (https://newsriver.io) is news crawling API that allowa you to get a stream of news from specific sources such us Reuters, Bloomberg, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at [Xignite](http://www.xiginite.com)?  There is a fee for it, but you can pull headlines and stories.

Here's a link to [more information](http://www.xignite.com/product/XigniteNews/api/) about their news feed.

It's a SOAP-based API.

HTH.

Comment: Xignite supports REST as well returning data in JSON, XML, or CSV.  See the API page for more details: https://www.xignite.com/product/XigniteNews/api/

Answer (score 3):

please use this api url to get news of us market, change s="" as per you search
http://feeds.finance.yahoo.com/rss/2.0/headline?s=a&region=US&lang=en-US

Answer (score 2):

Try Google's Finance feeds.

```
https://www.google.co.uk/finance/company_news?q=LON:VOD&output=rss
```

Just change the "q" URL argument to the stock you require.

Comment: it gives limited news is there any way to tweek the request to get more news like adding output size or something..

Answer (score 1):

Yahoo Finance provides an easy RSS feed with comma separated stock symbols. I used YQL to create a great web service that I later consume on my app.

Answer (score 0):

There aren’t really much APIs for stocks out there, fortunately, [Google](http://code.google.com/apis/finance/) provides you a free, yet powerful API to access the stock data that used in Google Finance. (Update once every 5 min, and up to 20 min of delay.)

Comment: do you know of any that provide recent market news?